# Import Azure Database to Local Not Supported

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, azure

I have a database, currently hosted out on Microsoft Azure. I exported the database to my storage account and I attempted to import the database to a local instance of SQL 2012.

When importing, I am able to copy the BACPAC file from Azure, but I get an error on "Creating database on target," with the error reading:

> Count not load schema model from package. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Internal Error.  The internal target platform type
>   SqlAzureDatabaseSchemaProvider does not support schema file version
>   '2.5'.

I have installed SQL Server Data Tools for 2012 from [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2012/12/13/available-today-ssdt-december-2012.aspx) download, which still was not able to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This was an old bug being reported a couple of years back that was fixed by an update to SSDT in 2012. Have you got this update: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

More discussion on Technet about this issue: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/66a4dfeb-c626-45eb-af3c-00e7e5996203/bacpac-file-import-from-windows-azure-fails?forum=ssdt